# How to include CASE statements in a SQL function definition

Tags: sql-function

The following function definition does not give any errors, but neither does it work as intended. Can anyone help?
It is *supposed* to return one of the text abbreviations when supplied an int:

```
CREATE FUNCTION foo(a int)
RETURNS character
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
  SELECT CASE C.INSURANCETYPE
    WHEN 0 THEN 'MB' --MEDICARE
    WHEN 1 THEN 'MC' --MEDICAID
    WHEN 2 THEN 'OF' --OTHER FED
    WHEN 3 THEN 'CH' --CHAMPVA
    WHEN 4 THEN 'CI' --GROUP
    WHEN 5 THEN 'OF' --OTHER FED
    WHEN 6 THEN 'CI' --OTHER GROUP
  END
  FROM C
$$;

SELECT foo(0);
```

...returns nothing

Comment: What makes it *not* "work as intended"? What happens when the query is run outside of the function? I would expect the same results.. and there is probably a missing ELSE.

Comment: try to set a variable to the select statement and do a return (variable name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
`CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION NUM_TO_INSURANCE(NUM int) RETURNS varchar AS $body$
declare REL varchar;
begin
SELECT 
  CASE NUM --block_1
    WHEN 0 THEN 'MB' --MEDICARE
    WHEN 1 THEN 'MC' --MEDICAID
    WHEN 2 THEN 'OF' --OTHER FED
    WHEN 3 THEN 'CH' --CHAMPVA
    WHEN 4 THEN 'CI' --GROUP
    WHEN 5 THEN 'OF' --OTHER FED
    WHEN 6 THEN 'CI' --OTHER GROUP
  END
   INTO REL;
RETURN REL;
END;
$body$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Declare @insuranceType as char

SET @insuranceType = (SELECT CASE C.INSURANCETYPE
    WHEN 0 THEN 'MB' --MEDICARE
    WHEN 1 THEN 'MC' --MEDICAID
    WHEN 2 THEN 'OF' --OTHER FED
    WHEN 3 THEN 'CH' --CHAMPVA
    WHEN 4 THEN 'CI' --GROUP
    WHEN 5 THEN 'OF' --OTHER FED
    WHEN 6 THEN 'CI' --OTHER GROUP
  END
  FROM C)

RETURN @insuranceType
```

Comment: This assumes its SQL Server, I always remember returning a value.

Comment: How do I store and use this as a function?

Comment: I just didnt include your code. So replace your SELECT statement with the above. I am doing this from memory so their might be a syntactical issue. It  looks right though :)